# Redefinition of mole 2019

Tags: mole, definitions

The mole was redefined in 2019 to $6.02214076\times 10^{23}$ elementary entities. I've learnt that this means that the mass of one mole of Carbon 12 is now no longer exactly 12g. However isn't Avagadros number or $6.02214076\times 10^{23}$ a measure of the number of atoms in 12g of Carbon 12? It seem this is no longer the case, so how exactly is Avagadros number now calculated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The [Avogadro constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) $N_A$ was the approximate number (as far as measurement allowed to know) of carbon-12 atoms in $\pu{12 g}$ of pure carbon-12 isotope.
- Now $N_A$ is   $\pu{6.02214076×10^23 mol-1}$ by definition, i.e. it is not calculated.

Therefore, $\pu{1 mol} = \pu{6.02214076×10^23}$ atoms of carbon-12 does not    have exactly the mass $\pu{12 g}$.

> It relates the molar mass constant $M_\mathrm{u}$ and the atomic mass constant $m_\mathrm{u}$ currently $\pu{1.66053906660(50)E−27 kg}$:
>
> $M_\mathrm{u} = m_\mathrm{u} N_\mathrm{A} = \pu{0.99999999965(30)E−3 kg⋅mol−1}$

Note that the element molar masses have uncertainty much bigger that the shift due Avogadro number redefinition, because of isotope abundance fluctuation.  The exception are elements with a single natural isotope, where it is comparable.